# Generate a binary matrix H knowing only the positions of the 1's

Tags: matlab, matrix

I would like to construct a binary matrix H of very large size, knowing only the positions of the '1's in the matrix.

For example if I know the following coordinates : `(1,1) = 1` , `(3,1) = 1` , `(2,2) = 1`, `(1,3) = 1`.The generated matrix gives : `H = [1 0 1 ; 0 1 0 ; 1 0 0]`

I tried to do it manually but with a very large matrix (For example `512*1024`) it becomes very complicated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a [sparse](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sparse.html) matrix:

```
% The coordinates
x = [1 3 2 1]
y = [1 1 2 3]

% Create a sparse matrix, then convert the sparse matrix to a full storage matrix
H = full(sparse(x,y,1))
```

Or even shorter (but using the same logic):

```
H = sparse(x,y,1)+0
% It works because matlab use an implicit class conversion
```

Comment: It should be noted that the OP's way of storing data is equivalent to sparse notation, which is why using `sparse` works so well in this scenario without any additional steps.